# Converting GdiPlus::Bitmap to OpenCV IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap, gdi+

I have a 24bpp `GdiPlus::Bitmap` that i need to convert into `IplImage` (opencv).
Does anyone know how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

1.) Create a new target IplImage object with the dimensions of Source image (GdiPlus::Bitmap)

2.) Get the pixeldata handle of Source image using lockbits

3.) Copy the source pixeldata to target imagedata

4.) UnlockBits of source image

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for your issue with the only difference, that BitMap converts to Mat: [Convert Bitmap to Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655452/convert-bitmap-to-mat)

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that Gdiplus::Bitmap supports lots of exotic pixel formats in theory, so in full generality the conversion would be verbose. However, the basic case is as follows:

```
IplImage* GdiPlusBitmapToOpenCvImage(Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmp)
{
    auto format = bmp->GetPixelFormat();
    if (format != PixelFormat24bppRGB)
        return nullptr;

    Gdiplus::Rect rcLock(0, 0, bmp->GetWidth(), bmp->GetHeight());
    Gdiplus::BitmapData bmpData;

    bmp->LockBits(&rcLock, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, format, &bmpData);

    int buffSz = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
    int depth = 8, channel = 3;
    IplImage* cvImage = cvCreateImage(CvSize(rcLock.Width, rcLock.Height), depth, channel);
    const unsigned char* src = static_cast<unsigned char*>(bmpData.Scan0);
    std::copy(src, src + buffSz, cvImage->imageData);

    bmp->UnlockBits(&bmpData);
    return cvImage;
}
```