# Converting System::Drawing::Bitmap^ to ::MAT

Tags: opencv, c++-cli

How converting image from picturebox to **::MAT** in C++/CLI?

Thank you

Comment: Probably you want to use `LockBits` to get a pointer to the array of pixel values.  Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24655452/103167

Comment: don't work, because this line `Gdiplus::Bitmap* enhanced = pictureBox1->Image;`, giving this error: _IntelliSense: a value of type "System::Drawing::Image ^" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Gdiplus::Bitmap *"_

Comment: Well of course you should use the C++/CLI syntax.  `System::Drawing::Bitmap` is a .NET wrapper around the native class `Gdiplus::Bitmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **[cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85af44e9(vs.80).aspx)** the Drawing.Image into a **[Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** (assuming that the image REALLY IS a bitmap).
Then lock the **[System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**, and use the Scan0 property of the BitmapData to access the inner buffer.

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap ^ bitmapFrame = safe_cast< System::Drawing::Bitmap ^ >(pictureBox1->Image);

BitmapData^ bmpData = bitmapFrame->LockBits(gcnew Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapFrame->Width, bitmapFrame->Height), System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, 
            bitmapFrame->Format);
try
{    
    void* data = bmpData.Scan0;

    //use the data in the ::Mat constructor.
}
finally { bitmapFrame->UnlockBits(bmpData); }//Remember to unlock!!!
```